# UDP broadcast, difference between XP and Vista

Tags: .net, udp, broadcast

I have come across some code that broadcasts UDP-messages.

On  Windows XP it  uses IpAdress.BroadCast, i.e. 255.255.255.255 but on Vista and newer the code checks all NICS and broadcast for each NIC on xxx.xxx.xxx.255 where x differs between different NICs.

To my knowledge the only difference between using xxx.xxx.xxx.255 versus 255.255.255.255 is that the latter never can leave the first router. I can't find information regarding if all the message goes out on teo nics. nics

What say you?

1) Are all NICS sent through using 255.255.255.255 ? 
2) Am I right regarding 255.255.255.255 residing iside one subnet?
3) Is there any merit to the code difference between XP and later OS:s?

Answer (score 0):

The "all ones" broadcast address (255.255.255.255) means broadcast on the local area network, whatever it happens to be.  If a system is connected to multiple subnets, this could mean broadcasting on all of them.  This address only applies to a network directly attached to the host: it should never be routed.

The subnet broadcast address (x.x.x.255 is just one example) means broadcast on *that* specific subnet.  If a system connected to multiple subnets, this would mean broadcasting on just one of them.  This address *may* be routed across the network: depending on router support you might be able to broadcast to all the systems on a subnet different than your own.

The "all ones" standard is older, so that's probably why XP uses it.

See [Broadcast address - Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Broadcast_address)